# How can I get the value of a at "t=2.4985352432136567" in the following expression?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

By running the following code:

```
a = Sin[y[t]];
sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[2][y][t] + 0.1*Derivative[1][y][t] + Sin[y[t]] == 0, 
Derivative[1][y][0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, y, 
{t, 0, 10}, Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> Derivative[1][y][t] - y[t]}]
```

we can obtain that the `"Event"` happens at `t = 2.4985352432136567` . 
The value of `y[2.4985352432136567]` can be obtained by using `y[2.4985352432136567] /. sol`, which appears to be `-0.589753`.

However, when I apply this method to `a` for `a[2.4985352432136567] /. sol`, the results appear to be `{Sin[InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 2.49854}}, <>][t]][2.49854]}`, and no specific value is obtained.

My question is, how can I get the specific value of `a` at `t = 2.4985352432136567`?

Comment: Try defining `a[t_] = Sin[y[t]]`.

Answer (score 9):

What I'd do is to define the solution as a regular function :

```
sol[t_] = NDSolve[{Derivative[2][y][t] + 0.1*Derivative[1][y][t] + Sin[y[t]] ==
  0, Derivative[1][y][0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, y[t], {t, 0, 10},  Method -> {"EventLocator", 
 "Event" -> Derivative[1][y][t] - y[t]}][[1, 1, 2]]
```

Now you can use it as any other function :

```
sol[2.4985352432136567]
(* -0.589753 *)

Plot[{sol[t], Sin[sol[t]]}, {t, 0., 2.4}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works well!

Comment: It's a bit cleaner to have the second argument of `NDSolve[]` be `y` instead of `y[t]`, methinks. Then, you can do something like `sol[t_] = y[t] /. First@NDSolve[eqns, y, {t, tmin, tmax}, opts]`...

Answer (score 7):

With your definition of `a`

```
 a[2.4985352432136567]
```

is `Sin[y[t]][2.49854]` (which explains the output you get from `a[2.4985352432136567] /.sol`)

To get `Sin[y[2.49854]]` you can use

```
 a /. t -> 2.4985352432136567 
 (*  Sin[y[2.49854]] *)
```

and

```
 a /. t -> 2.4985352432136567 /. sol
```

gives `{-0.556156}`.

Alternatively, you can make `t` an explicit argument of `a` as suggested in @b.gatessucks`s comment.

Comment: @SunnySky, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Sin[y[t]];
```

assigns the sine value to the variable `a`. If you would have defined the function `y[t]` to return a numeric value and have `t` assigned a value, then `a` would be assigned the numeric result of the function; otherwise, it would get the unevaluated value of `Sin[y[t]]`.

You use the `Set` function (`=`) to assign the value to `a`, which means that the RHS will be evaluated at the moment of the assignment, and won't change later. If you want `a` to change with the value of `t` you'll have to use `SetDelayed` (`:=`), then it will be evaluated each time it's referenced.

But that still leaves `a` as a variable, which you can't pass an argument to, like a function. If you want to define `a` as a function of `t`, you have to write it as

```
a[t_] = Sin[y[t]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, and it is helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

The `"EventAction"` sub-option of `"EventLocator"` seems to have not been mentioned thus far; this, in combination with the `Sow[]`/`Reap[]` pair, can be used to find all the values of `t` such that `y[t] == y'[t]`, and evaluate `Sin[y[t]]` at those points. Witness the following:

```
{fun, pts} = Reap[y /. First @
              NDSolve[{y''[t] + 0.1 y'[t] + Sin[y[t]] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0},
                      y, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> {"EventLocator",
                             "Event" -> y'[t] - y[t],
                             "EventAction" :> Sow[{t, Sin[y[t]]}]}]] // MapAt[First, #, 2] &
   {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>],
    {{2.49854, -0.556156}, {5.7876, 0.480503}, {9.03428, -0.413819}}}

Plot[{fun[t], Sin[fun[t]]}, {t, 0, 10},
     Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[7], Red, Point[pts]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot of solution and "special points"]